# which sequence type that does not support "extend slicing"?

Tags: python, slice

The python ref http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html
says that:

> Some sequences also support “extended slicing” with a third “step” parameter: a[i:j:k] selects all items of a with index x where x = i + n*k, n >= 0 and i <= x < j.

Then which sequence type that does not support "extend slicing" ?

Comment: Note that some objects that you *may* think are sequences, in fact aren't and they don't support slicing at all, e.g. [`deque`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/collections.html#collections.deque) raises `TypeError` even with `[start:stop]` syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These days, it'd be any user defined sequence that doesn't want/need to support it. All the current Python builtins do; In the *old days* - that wasn't the case... See http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0283/ and you'll see...

> Extended slice notation for all built-in sequences.  The patch
>         by Michael Hudson is now all checked in.

Which relates to:

http://docs.python.org/release/2.3.4/whatsnew/section-slices.html

> Ever since Python 1.4, the slicing syntax has supported an optional third `step'' or`stride'' argument. For example, these are all legal Python syntax: L[1:10:2], L[:-1:1], L[::-1]. This was added to Python at the request of the developers of Numerical Python, which uses the third argument extensively. However, Python's built-in list, tuple, and string sequence types have never supported this feature, raising a TypeError if you tried it. Michael Hudson contributed a patch to fix this shortcoming.